# When is it appropriate for the client to re-negotiate with SignalR Service?

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr, azure-functions, signalr.client

I'm trying to understand the access token returned by the `negotiate` step of `SignalR Service`.

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]HttpRequest req,
    [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "chat")]SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
{
    return connectionInfo;
}
```

- By default, how long is the token returned by `SignalRConnectionInfo` valid?
- Is there a way to manually configure the token lifespan?
- If the token is no longer valid, what happens to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection` object (particularly its `State` property)? Will it be set to `Disconnected`?

Basically, I'm trying to determine when I should **re-negotiate** to keep my connection open. In the event that the token expires, how can the client know it needs to negotiate one more time before being able to send and receive real time messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Drilling down into the [Azure SignalR SDK code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/e2989ede0fe5a12112aaa04057970d774f76b94c/src/Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Common/Constants.cs#L34), the default access token lifetime seems to be 1 hour.
2. While the [SDK seems to support customizing the lifetime](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/987800544ba435989f859cdedc7de4877ed070bb/src/Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Management/ServiceManager.cs#L127), the service [binding doesn't seem expose it](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension/blob/dev/src/SignalRServiceExtension/Client/AzureSignalRClient.cs#L55).

   With 3, don't think you would really need it but you could [raise on issue on its repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension) or contribute a PR to support it.
3. In the `@microsoft/signalr` package, you could either [enable automatic reconnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#automatically-reconnect) or [manually reconnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#manually-reconnect). I believe the library handles the negotiate calls internally on its own.

Answer (score 2):

In the Authentication and authorization section in the Microsoft documentation says:

> The access token function you provide is called before every HTTP request made by SignalR. If you need to renew the token in order to keep the connection active (because it may expire during the connection), do so from within this function and return the updated token.

So you need to send a "refreshed" token when you first start the connection. In an application context, when your token expires it should redirect the user to identity server to refresh the token and then start again a new connection.

In our company we have the persistent connection to the hub with the application token, so when it expires, it forces to refresh the token, and that will trigger a new connection to the hub with the new token.